# QGIS 3: Changing the datasource of a layer?

Tags: pyqgis-3

Everything seems to go right, but nothing happens:

```
layers = QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().values()
for layer in layers:
    if isinstance(layer, QgsVectorLayer):
        dp = layer.dataProvider()
        uri = QgsDataSourceUri(dp.dataSourceUri())
        print ("Origin: ", uri.connectionInfo())

      uri.setDatabase('P:/PG/GEM/BAV20/GEMEINDE365/31717/qgs/wh_2/31717.sqlite')
        #uri.setDatabase('./wh_2/31717.sqlite')
        print ("New:", uri.connectionInfo())
        dp.setDataSourceUri(uri.connectionInfo())
        dp.reloadData()
        layer.dataProvider().forceReload()
        layer.triggerRepaint()
```

What I am missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `dataProvider().forceReload()` function was removed in QGIS3, the docs are a bit out of date. New in 3.6 is the `setDataSource` function but it needs `ProviderOptions` as well so;

```
layer.setDataProvider(myParams, name, layer type, QgsDataProvider.ProviderOptions())
layer.triggerRepaint()
```

https://qgis.org/api/classQgsRasterLayer.html#a733cd12cd1a95248450d0b471996c53b

This works with a wms call havent tried with a DB connecting.